# Пирожки с вишнями

Tags: грамотная-речь

Кто-то знает, как правильно?
В основном слышу, что говорят "пирожки с вишней", но иногда кто-то говорит "пирожки с вишнями". Так как правильно говорить: "с вишнями" или "с вишней"?

Answer (score 2):

По всей видимости, не существует ясной закономерности, по которой за одними сущностями закрепилась одна гастрономическая трактовка (собирательная: клубника, черника, малина), а за другими - обе (собирательная и штучная: вишня - вишни, яблоко - яблоки, абрикос - абрикосы). В первом случае ни при каких условиях (ни дома, ни в общепите) нельзя приготовить блюдо с "клубниками", "малинами" или "черниками" (можно только представить себе такое как ботанический жаргон в разговоре о разных подвидах растений). Во втором случае - сложнее. В промышленной кулинарии к "вишне" применяют преимущественно собирательный вариант (с вишней, из вишни), а к яблокам - "штучный" (пироги, гусь или шарлотка "с яблоками"), как и в быту. За пределами коммерческой кухни с "вишней" поступают по-разному. Вот, к примеру, песня "*Вареники с вишнями*" (Л. Успенская). Представим себе, что название изменилось на альтернативное, и для многих это прозвучит как канцеляризм - как "кура" или "греча", как "план по яйцу". Ведь для кого-то "в маленьком саду созрели вишни". Так что подобное употребление, **по меньшей мере, допустимо**. В варенике обычно 1-2 вишенки, вот и с "пирожки" мало чем отличаются. Я бы уверенно сказал "*с вишнями*", поскольку для меня это домашняя еда и я с детства помню, как бабушка укладывала вишни по штучке в вареники или печенье, которое она называла "трубочками (с вишнями)". Так что пусть пирожки на ценнике производителя остаются "с вишней"; тому же, кто их будет есть, приятнее сознавать, что внутри "вишни", а  не какая-то бесформенная субстанция.

**P.S.** Не совсем блюдо, но у Пушкина в "Выстреле" можно встретить "фуражку, наполненную черешнями" (почти "фуражка с черешнями").

Comment: Александр, то же и к Вам. Дело просто в том, что отдельные ягоды от Вашей первой категории называются по-другому, чем собирательное от ягоды: *клубничины, черничины, малинины.*

Comment: А разве бывают блюда из клубничин, черничин или малинин?

Comment: Фактически бывают, просто их так не называют, видимо, как раз из-за этой разницы в названиях.

Answer (score 1):

Пироги бывают с яблоками, с вишней, с черникой. Вишня и черника здесь имеют собирательное значение (у яблок такого значения нет).

А вот бывают ли пироги и вареники с вишнями? Интересно, что вишня может иметь множественное число (тарелка с вишнями, спелые вишни), в то время как черника, малина воспринимаются только собирательно.

Поэтому пирог с вишней - это общепринятое название и собирательное значение, а пирог с вишнями может реально содержать в себе две-три целые ягоды.

**Обновление**

Если в каждый (маленький) пирожок положить по вишенке, то, наверное, получатся пирожки с вишнями. Вишню можно относить к собирательным существительным (как это обычно делается), а можно считать поштучно. Отсюда и получаются два грамматических варианта, которые к тому же соответствуют реальности.

Comment: А вы различаете "пироги" и "пирожки", о которых был вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Хороший вопрос. А главное, что поиск в словарях озадачивает.

[Вишня](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/759446) в словаре Ушакова:
3. собир. Ягоды этого дерева (разг.). На базар привезли много вишни.
То есть собирательное "вишня" разговорно по нему. И выходит, что строго правильнее сказать *"пирожки с вишнями".*

***Но*** теперь смотрим "сливу" в том же словаре и [находим](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1029082):
2. только ед., собир. Плоды этого дерева. Варенье из сливы. Варить сливу.
Собирательное "слива" даётся без пометки "разг.", а значит, правильно будет *"пирожки со сливой".*

Но, по-моему, это очень странно, что между употреблением созвучных ягод возникает такая разница. По крайней мере если бы меня спросили, как мне кажется, как правильно ответить на этот вопрос, то я бы сказал, что всегда лучше использовать плоды как собирательные: *пирожок с яблоком, вишней, сливой, абрикосом, лимоном и т. д.*

Comment: Пирожки, естественно, только с яблоками (а не с яблоком). И с абрикосами. Но с лимоном.

Comment: Хм, а для меня это не очевидно...

Comment: Ну как же... Большой урожай яблока? Или абрикоса?! Но вот с лимоном это не прокатывает. Урожай лимонов, но пирожки все-таки с лимоном.

Comment: Артем, на словарь  Ушакова не стоит ориентироваться, он устарел. В словаре Кузнецова нет пометы

Comment: Мне кажется, тут нюансы контекста, т. е. пирожки могут быть с абрикосом, но урожай, конечно, только абрикосов, и много абрикосов, но почему-то много вишни и, как мне кажется, сливы.

Comment: Если вишню брать собирательно, тогда - вишни. Если важно количество - вишен. Но вариант "пирожки с вишнями" мне кажется странным.

Comment: Если Ушаков устарел, то Кузнецов никогда и не был авторитетным.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно и то, и другое. Если интересует именно начинка, то лучше "с вишней". Это собирательное. С вишнями, только если они там целые.

Варение из вишни, не из вишен.

А насчет кулинарного вопроса - это вряд ли.

Comment: Варенье из вишни - правильное наименование, но излишне формальное: за пределами кухни говорят "вишнёвое варенье". Вряд ли в каком-нибудь повествовании встретится "он сидел и пил чай с вареньем из вишни",  хотя для полицейского протокола об отравлении такое подошло бы. :)

Comment: Мне не нравится "вишневое варенье". "Вишневый" для меня в первую очередь -- цвет.  И я думаю, что "за пределами кухни" меня поймут. Оно как раз "варенье из вишни, черной смородины, крыжовника, черноплодной рябины и т. д."  прилагательные мучают язык. Единственное исключение - "земляничный". Вот это слово очень люблю, что-то в нем родное и теплое. Может потому, что я еще застал время, когда в ближних подмосковных лесах эту землянику можно было собирать если не лукошками, то кружками... А сейчас и листика не найдешь...

Answer (score 0):

не знаю, как пирожки, но вареники с вишнями я есть не буду. Это вроде как вареники отдельно - вишня отдельно. С вишней - да.
С "яблоками"- не очевидно. Просто собирательные названия обычно имеют мелкие плоды и ягоды. Яблоко - как раз граница.
И насчет Ушакова и Пушкина. Есть такое предположение, что собирательные названия были всегда, но особой популярностью стали пользоваться относительно недавно. Поэтому и фуражка с черешнями и "разг" при собирательном "вишня".

Answer (score -2):

Вишня - дерево. То есть слово "вишни" - часто означает "вишнёвые деревья". Пирожки с вишнями - это пирожки с вишнёвыми деревьями. :) А пирожки с вишней - это уже с ягодами. ;)